# Why file still open after using in c#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, sorting, read-write

In my code, I have read and write in .csv file.

```
 using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(destFile, true))
            {
                string[] lines;
                file.WriteLine("Date,Entity, ProdFamily);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberFile; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(files[i]);
                    lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(files[i]);
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if (line != lines[0])
                        {  
                            file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},
                            values[43], values[0], values[3]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

After that, I write the code to `sort` the contain of the file.

```
var sorted =
            File.ReadLines(destFile)
                .Select(line => new {
                    SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[4]),
                    Line = line
                })
                .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
                .Select(x => x.Line);
            File.WriteAllLines(destFile, sorted);
```

However, the error shown saying that I still did not `close` my file. It says that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll

I try use `using` to ensure that the file is closed automatically but the error is still exist.

Comment: Have you ensured to call Flush() and Close() before disposing it?

Comment: @Edney: Neither of those should be necessary. The point of `Dispose` is that it should do everything you need.

Comment: Even use `using`, still need to use `Dispose`?

Comment: At the end of `using` block, it calls `Dispose` automatically, this is the purpose of `using` block: a temporary object that must be disposed after it's use. Just another C#'s syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code contained in the `using` is irrelevant here, and is closing the file correctly, the second block of code is at fault - enumerating the result of `File.ReadLines()` has opened the file for reading, and will not close it until the enumerator is closed. As a result, you can’t write to the same file while the enumeration is in progress.

Your options would seem to be either to write to a different file in your `File.WriteAllLines()` from the one you’re reading in `File.ReadLines()`, or you could ensure the enumeration is complete before writing the sorted data by adding a `.ToList()` after the last `.Select(...)` used to initialize `sorted`, or you could read all the lines in one go (so that the file is closed again before trying to write to it), by using `File.ReadAllLines()` instead of `File.ReadLines()`.

Comment: Calling ToArray() or ToList() wont execute the whole enumeration?

Comment: @edney - yes it will, I have added the `.ToList()` option to the answer.

Comment: I have used `File.WriteAllLines()` after the sorting. But it still says the file is used by other process.

Comment: @irhamdollah did you try writing to a *different* file from the one you’re reading from, or try replace `File.ReadLines()` with `File.ReadAllLines()`, or add a `.ToList()` at the end of the line that initialises `sorted`?

Comment: @Iridium I tried to write to a different file and use `.ToList()`. It says `input string was not in a correct format`.

Comment: @irhamdollah - the new error is unrelated to the one in your original question, it means there’s something wrong with the data in the input file, and so the `Int32.Parse(...)` is failing. It looks like in the first block of code you are adding a header line, perhaps that is the line causing the issue when you attempt to sort it later?

Comment: @Iridium thank you for the idea. I will try to use `Skip(1)` and `Concat` it again when I write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read from and write to a file like that at the same time. Plus it may not be a great idea if, for example, your program were to crash partway through.

The fault tolerant approach is to write the new data to a temporary file then rename it when you are done.

```
var sorted =
        File.ReadLines(destFile)
            .Select(line => new {
                SortKey = Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[4]),
                Line = line
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.SortKey)
            .Select(x => x.Line);

var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, sorted);
File.Move(tempFile, destFile, overwrite: true);
```

Comment: It shows error `input string was not in a correct format`